# Why is "lst.reverse()" so much faster than "lst[::-1]"?

Tags: python

Why is `lst.reverse()` so much faster than `lst[::-1]`? There seems to be a large time difference in both Python 3 and 2.

Example (Python 3.5)

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> lst = list('Crooked Hillary!') * 1000
>>> def TrumpWins(lst):
...    lst.reverse()
...    return lst
... 
>>> def SecondPlace(lst):
...   return lst[::-1]
...
>>> timeit(lambda: TrumpWins(lst), number=100000)
0.7976173080969602
>>> timeit(lambda: SecondPlace(lst), number=100000)
4.703373569995165
```

Comment: Are you just posting this for the purpose of Trumping it up?

Comment: I would say `reverse` uses a compiled `for` but `lst[::-1]` calls a not compiled `for`... but I might be totally wrong.
By the way, you're pretty likely to get banned with such an account name.

Comment: Not winning the popular vote here

Comment: @Right What policy is being broken with that account name…?

Comment: @deceze That's right, I thought there would be such rule but I cannot find any... my bad. Pretty savage, though.

Answer (score 14):

Jokes apart.

`lst[::-1]` returns a new list, while `list.reverse` simply performs a reversal of the list *inplace*. The extra overhead comes from creating a new list. And the cost/overhead will grow in proportion with the length of the list you're trying to reverse.

A fairer comparison might be to copy the list before invoking the `reverse` method:

```
In [14]: l = [1]*1000

In [15]: %%timeit
   ....: l[::-1]
   ....:
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.64 µs per loop 

In [16]: %%timeit
   ....: l[:].reverse()
   ....:
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.27 µs per loop
```

Nearly equal timings, with `reverse` losing out in this case due to the added overhead of the method call, as against the first case which uses a language construct.